# Can i edit an app after it's published to Google Play?

Tags: android, qr-code

Does Google Play give me a QR Code for my app?

If so does it work for Android and iPhones?

Does the QR Code download my app or just launch it?

I have searched entire site and then some. I cannot find any answers and it won't let me email developer support.

Comment: The QR would most likely bring up a webpage where it can be downloaded from.

Comment: http://qrcode.kaywa.com/ put your application google play application link that you've published https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.test and generate the QR code

Answer (score 1):

A QR Code just contains data, in this case it would contain a link.

So just find a tool or site that generates QR codes, and generate one from your apps link on google play, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourapp

And to answer the title, yes you can edit your app once its published. You can upload new versions. Just increment the version code and name.

Comment: Please refrain from asking people to vote/accept your answers. [See this meta post for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/152134). Thanks!